# requesting password reset in django

Tags: review

This is the problem i get when requesting password reset

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/

(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError d20sm16587244pjs.12 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/password-reset/
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     SMTPSenderRefused
Exception Value:    

(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError d20sm16587244pjs.12 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')

Exception Location:     C:\Users\bishw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py in sendmail, line 871
Python Executable:  C:\Users\bishw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
```

I havenot got any solution in google .
This is my first project in django.It is very difficult to find a way 
**My code**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting your machine must solve the issue. worked for me.